# Django filter query and or and

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to use AND OR AND in one filter method, is it possible to do without custom query?
Something like that: `.filter((Q(condtion) & Q(condition)) | (Q(condition) & Q(condition)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(Q(condition)&Q(condition))|Q(Q(condition)&Q(condition)))
```

Or

```
qa = Model.objects.filter(conditon_a='value', conditon_b='value')  # Or .filter(Q(conditon)&Q(condition))
qb = Model.objects.filter(conditon_a='value', conditon_b='value')

queryset = qa | qb
```

Comment: it doesn't work, just showing first condition results, I tried it before.

Comment: two ways works, thanks it was problem with my other code, I missed that. I tried something like first code block before :D